# Black and white TV show or movie with human sized bird creatures killing people at night

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I remember people trying to run from one house/cabin to another and being killed off by these man sized bird creatures, I think they had large beaks. this was taking place at night in an outdoor setting. I think this was a 60's or 70's TV thriller show or movie.

Comment: Err, could it be "The Birds"? http://25.media.tumblr.com/6a3fb5caa28afd143ecb20e8408e0233/tumblr_mhk2qaqujq1qa70eyo2_1280.jpg

Comment: @steve Were they actually flying Gargoyles instead of birds?

Answer (score 4):

Could it be 'Gargoyles' 1972 TV Movie?

Comment: @MrLister IIRC, some of the gargoyles did have beaks. Though not so large as to look like a pterodactyl, they were large enough to note. Not to date myself too much, I actually watched this movie when it first aired. It was pretty cool at the time so that's why I remember it now. It meets all of Steve's criteria but we still don't know if it's the movie he's looking for.

Comment: In that case, sorry. I don't know anything about this movie, apart from this clip, so just ignore me.

Comment: NP. If you get a chance you should try to watch it. It was kind of scary (for it's time) with a great story line.